# How to call a method when back button on a UINavigationController is pressed? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

How can I call a method when the back button on a `UINavigationController` is pressed. I need to be able to call a method before the previous view is displayed. Is this possible? If so please can someone advise on how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A fast solution is to add an implementation for the **viewWillDisappear:** method. It will be triggered as soon as the **viewController** will disappear in response to the back button pression.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  //... 
  //make you stuff here
  //... 
}
```

Another solution is to add a custom responder to the back button. You can modify your viewController's init method as follow:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //other your stuff goes here
        //... 
        //here we customize the target and action for the backBarButtonItem
        //every navigationController has one of this item automatically configured to pop back
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.target = self;
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.action = @selector(backButtonDidPressed:);
    }
    return self;
}
```

and then you can use a selector method as the following. Be sure to dismiss correctly the viewController, otherwise your navigation controller won't pop as wanted.

```
- (void)backButtonDidPressed:(id)aResponder {
    //do your stuff
    //but don't forget to dismiss the viewcontroller
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: One difference between the two is that the first solution (i.e. `viewWillDisappear`) is called when going back or forward through the navigation stack. The second solution is just for going back.

Comment: This won't normally work as you'll find that backBarButtonItem is nil unless you explicitly assign a button to it.  In my experience anyway, both leftBarButtonItem and backBarButtonItem were nil.

Comment: @Matt is right. It is called on calling any button that forwards to another screen

Comment: How does the destination view controller know that it's coming to the top of the stack? I'd like it to update based upon changes applied by the pushed/popped ViewController.

Comment: self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem reference is nil.

Answer (score 6):

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 52, 31)];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[backButton setTitle:@"CLOSE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedBackButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted];

UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
```

Create a custom Back Button and using that selector call a method that you want. And also use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

```
- (void)tappedBackButton:(id)button
{
    // call your method here
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: Note that when you replace the back button in this way, you lose the  "swipe from the left edge to return to the parent viewController" feature, which was introduced in iOS 7 and is a useful shortcut on iPhone 6 and 6+

Comment: This is not working with self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem...Please give another solution

Answer (score 6):

I think I found a "clean" way to do that :

First, set your view controller as complying with the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol

```
@interface MyViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Then, define it as the delegate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Set this View Controller as the navigation controller delegate
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;

}
```

Last, use this method from the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol :

```
#pragma mark - Navigation controller delegate
- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    // If there is no parent, then it means that the view controller has been removed from the stack, which happens when the back button has been pressed
    if (!parent) {
        NSLog(@"Back button pressed");

        // it can be useful to store this into a BOOL property
        self.backButtonPressed = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be, to put the code in the ViewController that will be presented when the back button is pressed. You can use `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     //Your code here
}
```

Note that this will also be executed when the view is presented for any other reason, so if you want it to happen only when the back button is pressed you have to use the delegate:
[UINavigationControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007662)

Comment: that method will be called when that vc appears at all, not necessarily just as a result of just going back to it

Comment: @Colin that is correct, it depends on the exact behavior he wants, he can use the delegate, if he only wants it when the back button is pressed.